# how greenplum partition support varchar datatype

Tags: database, greenplum

Script is:

```
create table T_RH_AJ_XW_JCJJJ2 (
   ZJ_ID                VARCHAR(32)          not null,
   JJ_RQ                VARCHAR(32),
   RK_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   GX_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   SJZT_W               VARCHAR(32)
)
distributed by (ZJ_ID)
partition by range (JJ_RQ)
(
     START ('2012-08-11'::date) END ('2012-08-12'::date)
     EVERY ( INTERVAL '1 day')
);
```

I want partition use varchar column（JJ_RQ datatype, and this column value is '2020-11-08';
but this is a error:

> error is 'operator does not exist: character varying + interval, No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Greenplum but it's based on PostgreSQL so I'll give it a try:

The `JJ_RQ` column should be of type `date` or `timestamp` because the `EVERY` clause is trying to add an `INTERVAL` value to i.

Comment: thank you !yes,i know if JJ_RQ is type of date or timestamp，it would be right, but i want to try type of varchar。

Comment: @suhenhappy You can't expect Greenplum to know what it means to add an `INTERVAL` to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your table so that jj_rq is either a timestamp or a date to do this the correct way. But if you must partition by a varchar, then you can use list partitioning.

```
create table T_RH_AJ_XW_JCJJJ2 (
   ZJ_ID                VARCHAR(32)          not null,
   JJ_RQ                VARCHAR(32),
   RK_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   GX_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   SJZT_W               VARCHAR(32)
)
distributed by (ZJ_ID)
partition by list (JJ_RQ)
(
     partition part1 values ('2012-08-11'),
     partition part2 values ('2012-08-12')
);
```

Small tables don't benefit from partitioning so I'm assuming that your table is on the larger size. To help reduce disk I/O, you should use append optimized tables and possibly compression too. The files are smaller and take less time to scan.

```
create table T_RH_AJ_XW_JCJJJ2 (
   ZJ_ID                VARCHAR(32)          not null,
   JJ_RQ                VARCHAR(32),
   RK_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   GX_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   SJZT_W               VARCHAR(32)
)
with (appendonly=true)
distributed by (ZJ_ID)
partition by list (JJ_RQ)
(
     partition part1 values ('2012-08-11'),
     partition part2 values ('2012-08-12')
);
```

And here is the best way to do this which is fixing your data type.

```
create table T_RH_AJ_XW_JCJJJ2 (
   ZJ_ID                VARCHAR(32)          not null,
   JJ_RQ                timestamp,
   RK_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   GX_SJ                TIMESTAMP,
   SJZT_W               VARCHAR(32)
)
with (appendonly=true)
distributed by (ZJ_ID)
partition by range (JJ_RQ)
(
START ('2012-08-11'::timestamp) END ('2012-08-12'::timestamp)
EVERY ( INTERVAL '1 day')
);
```

Comment: ,Thank you very much。I've add one column(Column:JJD_RQ type: date) to solve the problem；